# Type undefined is not assignable to type

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, apexcharts, donut-chart

Here, I am trying to implement pie chart (donut series) in angular.
These are my html, css and ts files.
I am following this resource.  https://apexcharts.com/angular-chart-demos/pie-charts/simple-donut/

Link to CodeSandBox - https://codesandbox.io/s/apx-donut-simple-8fnji?from-embed

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ChartComponent } from "ng-apexcharts";

import {
  ApexNonAxisChartSeries,
  ApexResponsive,
  ApexChart
} from "ng-apexcharts";

export type ChartOptions = {
  series: ApexNonAxisChartSeries;
  chart: ApexChart;
  responsive: ApexResponsive[];
  labels: any;
};

@Component({
  selector: 'app-second-page',
  templateUrl: './second-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./second-page.component.css']
})
export class SecondPageComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild("chart") chart: ChartComponent;
  public chartOptions: Partial<ChartOptions>;

  constructor() {
    this.chartOptions = {
      series: [44, 55, 13, 43, 22],
      chart: {
        type: "donut"
      },
      labels: ["Team A", "Team B", "Team C", "Team D", "Team E"],
      responsive: [
        {
          breakpoint: 480,
          options: {
            chart: {
              width: 200
            },
            legend: {
              position: "bottom"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    };
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

```css
  #chart {
    max-width: 380px;
    margin: 35px auto;
    padding: 0;
  }
```

```html
  <div id="chart">
    <apx-chart
      [series]="chartOptions.series"
      [chart]="chartOptions.chart"
      [labels]="chartOptions.labels"
      [responsive]="chartOptions.responsive"
    ></apx-chart>
  </div>
```

I am facing the undefined issue, but its working for them in the tutorial. Somebody please help me on this.

```
Error: src/app/second-page/second-page.component.html:32:8 - error TS2322: Type 'ApexNonAxisChartSeries | undefined' is not assignable to type 'ApexAxisChartSeries | ApexNonAxisChartSeries'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'ApexAxisChartSeries | ApexNonAxisChartSeries'.

32       [series]="chartOptions.series"
          ~~~~~~

  src/app/second-page/second-page.component.ts:19:16
    19   templateUrl: './second-page.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component SecondPageComponent.


Error: src/app/second-page/second-page.component.html:33:8 - error TS2322: Type 'ApexChart | undefined' is not assignable to type 'ApexChart'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'ApexChart'.

33       [chart]="chartOptions.chart"
          ~~~~~

  src/app/second-page/second-page.component.ts:19:16
    19   templateUrl: './second-page.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component SecondPageComponent.


Error: src/app/second-page/second-page.component.html:35:8 - error TS2322: Type 'ApexResponsive[] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'ApexResponsive[]'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'ApexResponsive[]'.

35       [responsive]="chartOptions.responsive"
          ~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/second-page/second-page.component.ts:19:16
    19   templateUrl: './second-page.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component SecondPageComponent.


Error: src/app/second-page/second-page.component.ts:23:23 - error TS2564: Property 'chart' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.

23   @ViewChild("chart") chart: ChartComponent;
                         ~~~~~

✖ Failed to compile.
```

Comment: try to declare chartOptions as an interface instead of a type

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure about the specifics of the library, but I can explain what the compiler is complaining about.

Whenever you use `Partial` in TypeScript, this can be seen as making all keys in the subject interface optional, for example

```
interface SomeInterface {
  key1: string;
  key2: number;
}

type PartialSomeInterface = Partial<SomeInterface>

// which is equivalent to
interface PartialSomeInterface {
  key1?: string;
  key2?: number;
}

// which is equivalent to
interface PartialSomeInterface {
  key1: string | undefined;
  key2: number | undefined;
}
```

Effectively, by declaring `chartOptions` as `Partial<ChartOptions>` you are saying that the object being stored may have as little as 0 keys, i.e. all of them may be missing or `undefined`, and that is an acceptable value for `chartOptions`.

When a property on this `chartOptions` is then passed to the `<apx-chart>` component, the chart component needs to have `| undefined` in the type definition for the property being passed in. For example, looking at the `series` input:

```
// Component definition needed
@Input() series?: ApexAxisChartSeries | ApexNonAxisChartSeries

or

@Input() series: ApexAxisChartSeries | ApexNonAxisChartSeries | undefined
```

The compiler is complaining that this is not the case, and a value of `undefined` is not acceptable. Which most likely means that the component definition is in fact:

```
@Input() series: ApexAxisChartSeries | ApexNonAxisChartSeries
```

In short `Partial<ChartOptions>` does not appear to be an acceptable type for `chartOptions` based on the demands of the child component `<apx-chart>`.

This is confusing, as you have quite rightly followed the documentation/example provided.

Couple of things to try/investigate:

- As you are fortunate enough to have defined all of the properties of the `ChartOptions` interface in your `chartOptions` variable initial values, simply remove the `Partial`. This will tell the underlying component that every property in `chartOptions` is expected to be defined, and therefore all 4 keys can be passed into the component as you have done
- If you still need to use `Partial`, i.e. you intend to not define all starting properties of `chartOptions`, is there a chance that the version of `apx-chart` you are using is outdated/does not match the version used in the demos?

Comment: As you mentioned above, I removed the Partial.
Now I'm getting only one error.



Error: src/app/second-page/second-page.component.ts:23:23 - error TS2564: Property 'chart' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.

23   @ViewChild("chart") chart: ChartComponent;
                         ~~~~~
✖ Failed to compile.

Comment: This may fix your issue: `@ViewChild("chart") chart!: ChartComponent`, note the `!` after `chart`. You're telling the compiler to expect that variable to be provided at some point. However if you try to access `this.chart` before it is ready (typically will be available  in/after the `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle hook), you may still get errors

Answer (score 0):

See the last error, it shows you the problem:

```
error TS2564: Property 'chart' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.
```

It's related to the typescript flag `--strictPropertyInitialization` introduced in [version 2.7](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#strict-class-initialization).

If `--strictPropertyInitialization` is enabled, the compiler checks if all properties of the component are initialized. [+info](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictPropertyInitialization)

There are several ways to fix that. For example, disable `--strictPropertyInitialization` flag in typescript compiler options in `tsconfig.json` file.

```
"compilerOptions": {
...
  "strictPropertyInitialization":false
...
}
```

Comment: I did as you mentioned. Made --strictPropertyInitialization:false.
Project compiled successfully. But, it is still showing error in 'Problems' tab.
Property 'chart' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.
Shall I proceed with this in production level application ??

Comment: Have you tried to restart your IDE?